# Decoding AAC audio stream coming from red5 server with javacv-ffmpeg on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, red5, javacv, live-streaming

I am trying to play AAC audio live stream coming from Red5 server, so to decode the audio data i am using Javacv-ffmpeg. Data is received as **packets of byte[]**
Here is what i tried

```
public Frame decodeAudio(byte[] adata,long timestamp){
    BytePointer audio_data = new BytePointer(adata);
    avcodec.AVCodec codec1 = avcodec.avcodec_find_decoder(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);// For AAC 
    if (codec1 == null) {
    Log.d("showit","avcodec_find_decoder() error: Unsupported audio format or codec not found: " +  audio_c.codec_id() + ".");
    }
    audio_c = null;

    audio_c = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_context3(codec1);
    audio_c.sample_rate(44100);
    audio_c.sample_fmt(3);
    audio_c.bits_per_raw_sample(16);
    audio_c.channels(1);
    if ((ret = avcodec.avcodec_open2( audio_c, codec1, (PointerPointer)null)) < 0) {
    Log.d("showit","avcodec_open2() error " + ret + ": Could not open audio codec.");
    }

   if (( samples_frame = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_frame()) == null)
    Log.d("showit","avcodec_alloc_frame() error: Could not allocate audio frame.");

   avcodec.av_init_packet(pkt2);

   samples_frame = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_frame();
   avcodec.av_init_packet(pkt2);
   pkt2.data(audio_data);
   pkt2.size(audio_data.capacity());
   pkt2.pts(timestamp);
   pkt2.pos(0);

   int len = avcodec.avcodec_decode_audio4( audio_c,  samples_frame,  got_frame,  pkt2);
}
```

But len after decoding returns -1 for first frame and then -22 always.
First packet is like this always

```
AF 00 12 08 56 E5 00
```

Further packets are like

```
AF 01 01 1E 34 2C F0 A4 71 19 06 00 00 95 12 AE AA 82 5A 38 F3 E6 C2 46 DD CB 2B 09 D1 00 78 1D B7 99 F8 AB 41 6A C4 F4 D2 40 51 17 F5 28 51 9E 4C F6 8F 15 39 49 42 54 78 63 D5 29 74 1B 4C 34 9B 85 20 8E 2C 0E 0C 19 D2 E9 40 6E 9C 85 70 C2 74 44 E4 84 9B 3C B9 8A 83 EC 66 9D 40 1B 42 88 E2 F3 65 CF 6D B3 20 88 31 29 94 29 A4 B4 DE 26 B0 75 93 3A 0C 57 12 8A E3 F4 B9 F9 23 9C 69 C9 D4 BF 9E 26 63 F2 78 D6 FD 36 B9 32 62 01 91 19 71 30 2D 54 24 62 A1 20 1E BA 3D 21 AC F3 80 33 3A 1A 6C 30 3C 44 29 F2 A7 DC 9A FF 0F 99 F2 38 85 AB 41 FD C7 C5 40 5C 3F EE 38 70
```

Couldn't figure out where is the problem, whether in setting the AVcodec context audio_c or setting packet for decoder.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first packet (config) describes the stream data if I'm not mistaken the follow on data is the encoded audio. You can't assume the sample rate etc.. as you have done above, you need to pull that out of the config data which is marked "AF 00".

Comment: will you suggest from where should i consider the data to be fed to the decoder, data from start AF 00 ... or ignoring AF only..

Comment: I'd seen a better breakdown of the acc data here on SO, but I can't find it. I'll have to point you at these articles to help you out: http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Understanding_AAC#Packaging.2FEncapsulation_And_Setup_Data and http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPEG-4_Audio

Comment: After lots of days.. i found that discarding first **AF 00** data in the packet , and setting correct number of channels ( in my case it is 2) and channel layout and profile type for audio context made the decoder to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I've intercepted the packets with Wireshark and here is what it told me:
AF is the control byte of AAC frame, and it decodes to following bits:

```
1010 .... = Format: HE-AAC
.... 11.. = Sample rate: 44kHz (allthough FFMPEG shows me 48kHz and I would lean to believe it more)
.... ..1. = Sample size: 16 bit
.... ...1 = Channels: stereo
```

I still can't figure out how to universally decode this data.

edit:
Ha! I've got something :)
I guess the first 2 bytes are RTMP specific bytes. The second one seems to state, whether it is the configuration (0) or actual payload (1) - i've found no sources confirming that, it is just my assumption.
Then the first, short package is the AAC configuration description described here:
http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2010/03/aac-configuration.html

In my case it is:

```
11 90
```

which is binary:

```
0001 0001 1001 0000
```

and that decodes to:

```
0001 0... .... .... = 2 = AAC LC
.... .001 1... .... = 3 = 48 kHz
.... .... .001 0... = 2 = 2 channels (stereo)
.... .... .... .0.. = 0 = 1024 sample length
.... .... .... ..0. = 0 = doesn't depends on core code (?)
.... .... .... ...0 = 0 = extension flag
```